# Can the position of pixel be changed from Pixel Shader in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna-4.0, pixel-shader

I need to change the position of each pixel: ex. (33,30) -> (40,55) and so on.
Can it be done inside Pixel Shader in XNA 4.0?

Comment: No, it's not possible to do this.  If you edit your question to describe what it is you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to help you figure out the correct methodology.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a Texture2D object to Pixel Shader in XNA 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321307/how-to-pass-a-texture2d-object-to-pixel-shader-in-xna-4-0)