# Loading texture to GPU for shader processing in SharpDX

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sharpdx

I am trying to use a texture from a shader on Windows Phone 8 using SharpDX, but I have trouble uploading the texture to GPU. I've found these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.textures.aspx
[How to pass a Texture2D object to Pixel Shader in XNA 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321307/how-to-pass-a-texture2d-object-to-pixel-shader-in-xna-4-0)

Unfortunately, I don't have `GraphicsDevice.Textures` property available in SharpDX. I couldn't find a way to upload my `Texture2D` object to the GPU. How do I upload my texture to GPU under SharpDX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found out how to do it myself:

`shader = Content.Load<Effect>("Shader.tkfxo");` is my shader.

When I was debugging, I found the `Parameters` property of the effect. I've found that the index at `2` was corresponding to a `Texture2D` object. It was looking for an array so I used `shader.Parameters[2].SetResource<Texture2D>(new Texture2D[] { myTextureObject });` and it worked flawlessly.